# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am creating an torrent application using libtorrent in VS 2008. I tried the example given in the link http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/examples.html
BUt it is showing me these error....how to solve them?

```
Linking...
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall libtorrent::torrent_info::~torrent_info(void)" (??1torrent_info@libtorrent@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall libtorrent::torrent_info::torrent_info(struct libtorrent::lazy_entry const &)" (??0torrent_info@libtorrent@@QAE@ABUlazy_entry@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl libtorrent::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,struct libtorrent::lazy_entry const &)" (??6libtorrent@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV12@ABUlazy_entry@0@@Z) referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl libtorrent::lazy_bdecode(char const *,char const *,struct libtorrent::lazy_entry &,int)" (?lazy_bdecode@libtorrent@@YAHPBD0AAUlazy_entry@1@H@Z) referenced in function _main
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall libtorrent::lazy_entry::clear(void)" (?clear@lazy_entry@libtorrent@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall libtorrent::lazy_entry::~lazy_entry(void)" (??1lazy_entry@libtorrent@@QAE@XZ)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl libtorrent::to_hex(char const *,int,char *)" (?to_hex@libtorrent@@YAXPBDHPAD@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl libtorrent::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class libtorrent::big_number const &)" (??6libtorrent@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV12@ABVbig_number@0@@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: struct libtorrent::peer_request __thiscall libtorrent::file_storage::map_file(int,__int64,int)const " (?map_file@file_storage@libtorrent@@QBE?AUpeer_request@2@H_JH@Z) referenced in function "public: struct libtorrent::peer_request __thiscall libtorrent::torrent_info::map_file(int,__int64,int)const " (?map_file@torrent_info@libtorrent@@QBE?AUpeer_request@2@H_JH@Z)
C:\Users\photoshop3\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Lib2\Debug\Lib2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The .lib is not included in your project. Make sure you are linking it in;
Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Another altnerative is to simply copy the .lib to your project folder but don't, it's bound to create problems later on.

Sometimes the .lib is not shipped with the library, so you need to compile it yourself. 
The README will tell you this. If this is the case, they usually ship with a .sln file you can open and the just compile it into a .lib file which you then reference in your main application, as I wrote above

Comment: I added the libtorrent-rasterbar.lib but its showing error: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libtorrent-rasterbar.lib'  now where can I find this :(

Comment: Browse the your libtorrent folder and see if the file exists in the first place. If not, you need to compile it yourself.

Comment: NO the file is missing...how to compile it..please tell me

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the path of header files in the "Configuration Properties" --> "C/C++“ --> "General" --> "Additional Include Directories"?

Answer (score 2):

The [link](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/examples.html) gives you only the sources (including headerfiles) of libtorrent. You should compile this sources to get a .lib file. Add this .lib file to your client:

Configuration Properties/Linker/Input -> Additional Dependencies: `libtorrent-rasterbar.lib`

The best starting point for compiling should be the README file.

Comment: how to create this libtorrent-rasterbar.lib I dont find it any where

Comment: in README nothing about the lib creation is given. I tried with the techniques given in this http://limewire.negatis.com/index.php?title=Visual_Studio_libtorrent  but still not able to create lib file

Comment: README includes to build instruction. 

(1) See docs/manual.html



(2) run: ./configure

Followed by

   make

Answer (score 1):

`public:` isn't the unresolved symbol. It's just there because the linker it trying to tell you that (most) of the unresolved symbols are public member functions.

It looks like you've included the header for "libtorrent", but not linked to the "libtorrent" library.

Comment: yes I am using the libtorrent & in the LInker>General>Additional Library Directories I have added : C:\boost\boost_1_36_0\stage\lib; "C:\Users\photoshop3\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Lib2\libtorrent"     what else I have to do?

Comment: @amrit_neo: you have to add the correct library file in the project settings as well. [Project Properties | Configuration Properties | Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies]

Comment: Sorry but I am new to VS and this libtorrent. Which one I should add. Previously I have created an app with a browser embedded to it in that I have added comctl32.lib. Adding this still not solving my problem

Answer (score 1):

You have probably not linked with the torrent library or specified the wrong path to it so that the linker cannot find it.

Comment: yes I am using the libtorrent & in the LInker>General>Additional Library Directories I have added : C:\boost\boost_1_36_0\stage\lib; "C:\Users\photoshop3\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Lib2\libtorrent" what else I have to do?

Comment: I have added the header files but where I can get the library for torrent?

Comment: You can download the version you need from the downloads section of rasterbar software (http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the input libraries are of 32bit and your are using them in building a 64bit it might be one of the reasons

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had it included in my project, but it turned out that it was a plugin that was designed to not create an instance of in my unit test.