# libtorrent unresolved external

Tags: c++, compilation, unresolved-external, libtorrent

I'm getting the following error when I compile my program which links to libtorrent.lib. I've tried compiling libtorrent with different settings, I've tried enabling/disabling DHT, deprecated functions, etc.

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   libtorrent::rel_performancetimer_pools_nolog_resolvecountries_deprecated_dht_ext_(void)"

Is anyone here familiar with libtorrent, or can anyone provide any advice for getting rid of this error? I don't see any other libraries that I need to link to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790751/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-public)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my definitions in my project were inconsistent with the configuration/definitions in the libtorrent compilation, so some macros were calling a function that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

I've spent two days on it and finally I've found an issue.
Name of this function "void rel_performancetimer_pools_nolog_resolvecountries_deprecated_dht_ext_" consists of the parts, that describes your current preferences. For example, dht_ means you're using DHT, and nolog_ means you're switched off TORRENT_LOGGING directive.
The problem is: this settings works only with Release configuration! rel_ means release_. On the libtorrent 0.16.11 this problem still not solved.
I've put this text in file build_config.hpp on the line 40:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define TORRENT_DEBUG
#endif
```

This is the way to compile my project with libtorrent in release and debug configurations, without making any corrections. 
Arvid, please, include this 3 lines to your next version of libtorrent. 
Appreciated,
Ilya from Russia.

Comment: Arvid forgot to pay for the DNS name registration.

Comment: I added an additional condition inside: `#ifndef TORRENT_DEBUG`... This allows you to avoid compiler warnings about redefinition `TORRENT_DEBUG` specified on the command line when building the library.