# libtorrent-rasterbar and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I'm trying to build a simple code (examples/simple_client.cpp) using libtorrent-rasterbar with VS2013 (C++), but I get the following linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl libtorrent::rel_performancetimer_pools_nolog_resolvecountries_deprecated_nodht_ext_(void)" (?rel_performancetimer_pools_nolog_resolvecountries_deprecated_nodht_ext_@libtorrent@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall libtorrent::session::session(struct libtorrent::fingerprint const &,int,unsigned int)" (??0session@libtorrent@@QAE@ABUfingerprint@1@HI@Z)
```

I compile libtorrent using: `bjam toolset=msvc-12.0 link=static variant=debug boost=source` and link everything in VS:

- libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib
- libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib
- libtorrent.lib

Additional info:
libtorrent-rasterbar-0.16.15; boost_1_55_0; Windows 8.1 64bits.

Any ideas on what's going wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: I've seen the same problem in VS2012 days ago.

Comment: did you have included also library paths in your project? It also seems from the error that that method uses some deprecated code. Maybe you must define some define in library compilation in order to use it?

Comment: Yes, I've included lib paths. According to libtorrent doc, the build flag 'deprecated-functions' is set to on by default.

Comment: did you check the RSP response files in the output bjam directories to see which #define symbols you need ?

Comment: I just checked it (libtorrent.lib.rsp), but it only lists .obj files (sorry, I'm not really familiar with bjam builds).

Comment: I checked 'simple_client.obj.rsp' and found these definitions: 
`#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB 
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_CANCELIO 
#define BOOST_ASIO_HASH_MAP_BUCKETS = 1021 
#define BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION 
#define BOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE 
#define BOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK = 1 
#define TORRENT_DEBUG 
#define TORRENT_DISABLE_GEO_IP 
#define TORRENT_USE_TOMMATH 
#define UNICODE 
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE_`

but the error persists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research and tests, I managed to build the project. That's what I did:

1. Compiled using `bjam toolset=msvc-12.0 geoip=off
   resolve-countries=off link=static variant=debug boost=source` that
   way **geoip** and **resolve-countries** is disabled.
2. Using @Hernán's tip of checking the libtorrent RSP files, I got the
   following preprocessor definitions:

   - BOOST_ASIO_SEPARATE_COMPILATION
   - BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
   - BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_CANCELIO
   - BOOST_ASIO_HASH_MAP_BUCKETS=1021
   - BOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE
   - BOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1
   - TORRENT_DISABLE_GEO_IP
   - TORRENT_DISABLE_RESOLVE_COUNTRIES
   - TORRENT_USE_I2P=1
   - TORRENT_USE_TOMMATH
   - UNICODE
   - WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
   - _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
   - _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
   - _SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
   - _UNICODE
   - _WIN32
   - _WIN32_WINNT=0x0500
   - __USE_W32_SOCKETS
3. I added these definitions in VS. For debug configuration, one more
   definition was necessary: **TORRENT_DEBUG** (important).

Some websites I used:

- https://code.google.com/p/libtorrent/issues/detail?can=2&q=545&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&sort=-id&id=545
- [libtorrent unresolved external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960365/libtorrent-unresolved-external)

Thank you for the help.