# Error when running example program Magick++ imporing libraries into Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, magick++

I copied all the libraries and header files in to Visual C++ 2010 but couldn't be able to run any of the example program as i am continously getting this error for the past 2 days.

```
1>e:\program files (x86)\imagemagick-6.8.1-q16\include\magick++\stl.h(1867): warning C4251: 'Magick::x11DisplayImage::_display' : class 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Magick::x11DisplayImage'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>man.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall Magick::Image::~Image(void)" (__imp_??1Image@Magick@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>man.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Magick::Image::write(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_?write@Image@Magick@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>man.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Magick::Image::pixelColor(long,long,class Magick::Color const &)" (__imp_?pixelColor@Image@Magick@@QAEXJJABVColor@2@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>man.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall Magick::Color::~Color(void)" (__imp_??1Color@Magick@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>man.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Magick::Geometry::~Geometry(void)" (__imp_??1Geometry@Magick@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>man.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Magick::Image::Image(class Magick::Geometry const &,class Magick::Color const &)" (__imp_??0Image@Magick@@QAE@ABVGeometry@1@ABVColor@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>man.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Magick::Geometry::Geometry(char const *)" (__imp_??0Geometry@Magick@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>man.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Magick::Color::Color(char const *)" (__imp_??0Color@Magick@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>man.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl Magick::InitializeMagick(char const *)" (__imp_?InitializeMagick@Magick@@YAXPBD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Z-Axis\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\sassada\Debug\sassada.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

it merits mentioning that i downloaded Magick++ dll.

**Updated:**

After including libraries that comes with Magick++,

I am getting these errors now,

```
1>e:\program files (x86)\imagemagick-6.8.1-q16\include\magick++\stl.h(1867): warning C4251: 'Magick::x11DisplayImage::_display' : class 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Magick::x11DisplayImage'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Z-Axis\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\sassada\Debug\sassada.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

What does this mean ?

```
needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'Magick::x11DisplayImage'
```

Comment: There's likely a .lib you're not linking with. In your project properties, under Linker->Input you probably need to include whatever .lib files came along with it. these might be something like CORE_DB_magick++.lib.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790751/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-public)

Comment: kindly have a look at the updated question @Aeluned