# Can't Build PortAudio - "LNK1104: cannot open file 'ksguid.lib'"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, portaudio

I'm a beginner in C/C++, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to build the PortAudio library so I can use it in one of my project. I'm using VS 2013, the preset project-file for builds had to be converted to my version. I've been able to fix all the many problems that occurred on my long way here, except one:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ksguid.lib'
```

I've seen [this](https://bitbucket.org/undergraver/codetrainer/wiki/Building%20portaudio%20with%20Visual%20Studio) and [this](http://music.columbia.edu/pipermail/portaudio/2011-August/012848.html) site. All of them address exactly this problem, yet non of them has been able to solve it. Here are the solutions these sites suggest:

- Add `WASAPI` - symbol to `portaudio.def`,
- Add `PA_WDMKS_NO_KSGUID_LIB` - definition to the preprocessor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the `ksguid.lib`-file from the [Windows 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279). It might even already be installed on your computer. It's best to use the explorer to find it (probably `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64`).

When you found it, go back to Visual Studio and go to **Project** > **Properties** > **Configuration-Properties** > **Linker** > **Input**, then click on the little arrow on the right of **Additional Dependencies** and choose **edit**:
[image: What-To-Click]

Enter the absolute filepath to `ksguid.lib`. Make sure that you surrounded it with `"`-s and that you put a `;` at the end. (Throws an error without a usable description otherwise - Microsoft as we know it.)

Source: [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/undergraver/codetrainer/wiki/Building%20portaudio%20with%20Visual%20Studio), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790751/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-public)

Answer (score 1):

ksguid.lib is included in the Windows 7, 8, 8.1, and windows 10 sdk.  The answer provided by @Nearoo is perfectly valid.  This alternative answer involves modifying what directories the portaudio Visual Studio project looks for library files.

For reference, I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 8.1 PC. 
Navigate to: **Project** -> **Properties** -> **VC++ Directories**
At the top of the window,

1. change Configuration to "All Configurations".
2. change Platform to "All Platforms"
3. In the "Library Directories" portion, add the following path:

   $(WindowsSdkDir)\Lib\winv6.3\km\$(PlatformTarget)\

This nice thing is that this one path uses macros so it will work with Debug, Release, 32 bit and 64 bit builds of portaudio.