# Portaudio error "LNK1104: cannot open file 'ksguid.lib' " file not on my computer?

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, portaudio, asio

I'm trying to compile portaudio in visual studio 2015 and I encountered this common problem with the missing ksguid.lib file, I found this question on stackoverflow which suggested to create a link to the file in windows sdks directory.

The problem is that I don't have ksguid.lib in my windows sdks folder and now I'm stuck, is there an easy way to fix this? the original question I found is contained in the link below

[Can't Build PortAudio - "LNK1104: cannot open file 'ksguid.lib'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550887/cant-build-portaudio-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-ksguid-lib)

Comment: It is not an SDK file anymore.  It was moved into the WDK, the device driver development kit.  Which you probably don't have installed, [start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx).  Or use the version 7.1 SDK, as recommended in that duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after following the link posted by Hans Passant I managed to download the latest drivers and by linking ksguid.lib to my portaudio project I was able to build the solution.