# LINK1104 cannot open boost static library using visual studio 2008 command prompt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost

I'm trying to compile a cpp file which uses static boost libraries. I'm using the visual studio 2008 command prompt as I have not set up a VS project file.

The command I'm using is (run from the folder containing my source code):

`cl /EHsc /I "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0" Client.cpp`

The error is:

`LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-s-1_53.lib'`

However, the file 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-s-1_53.lib' can be found in "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib" so my understanding is that I've installed boost properly and I'm just failing to link to it?

I've tried including it directly using

`cl /EHsc /I"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0" /I "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib\" Client.cpp` 
which gives the same error.

I've also tried linking to it directly using /link as follows:
`cl /EHsc /I"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0" /link "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-vc90-mt-s-1_53.lib" Client.cpp`

Which returns a different error:
`cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename`

I seem to be calling the compiler flags wrong? But I can't see where/how.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789912/1link-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-system-vc90-mt-gd-1-36),but the solution involves issues with how visual studio/ the project file is set up. Since I don't have a project file, is there an easy solution for the above that I can't see or would I need to set up a project?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker needs to be told where the library file is located. You were very close with the last command line, but the file name needs to precede the `/link` option. This should work:

> cl /EHsc /I"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0" Client.cpp /link "C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-vc90-mt-s-1_53.lib"

Also, when linking to multiple libraries in the same directory, it is more concise to use the `LIBPATH` option to tell the linker where to look for *.lib* files.

> cl /EHsc /I"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0" Client.cpp /link "libboost_system-vc90-mt-s-1_53.lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib\"

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick, and the /LIBPATH tip saved me some time too. YAY :)