# Error LINK1104 cannot open file 'glut32.lib'

Tags: c++

I would like to open an existing project in VS2012 at compile time I get the following error:

> LNK1104 can not open file 'glut32.lib'

I opened the properties window and I set the linker to the folder that contains `glut32.lib`. 
I also copied the library in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC`, but I still have problems.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Copy it in your current build directory.

Comment: `VS2012`'s dir is `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0`, isn't it?

Comment: Why is your project using glut? There are much better more modern alternatives like GLFW.

Comment: Thanks @Blacktempel, but glut32.lib is also present in the project folder. Johny you are right, I was wrong to open the folder, because I also installed VS2010. Overv I can not use anything else because I use the library provides glut32.lib.

Comment: Are you building a 32 bit application?

Comment: @drescherjm My application is 32 bit

Comment: see this same question,add path and specify lib name,see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017041/link1104-cannot-open-boost-static-library-using-visual-studio-2008-command-promp)